# Linphone-Android SIP liberary compile error

Tags: android, android-ndk, sip, voip

I am trying to compile linphone-android library for last couple of days and I am facing below mentioned issue. According to read-me file when I shoot this command **./prepare_sources.sh**
I observed there is an error which is mentioned below.

Making all in downloads
cd ../src; rm *.c *.h &> /dev/null; awk -f /Users/gulfamhassan/Documents/githubs/linphone-android/submodules/libilbc-rfc3951/downloads/extract-cfile.awk \
        /Users/gulfamhassan/Documents/githubs/linphone-android/submodules/libilbc-rfc3951/downloads/rfc3951.txt > /dev/null
awk: syntax error at source line 1 source file /Users/gulfamhassan/Documents/githubs/linphone-android/submodules/libilbc-rfc3951/downloads/extract-cfile.awk
 context is

> > > < <<< HTML>
> > >       awk: bailing out at source line 10
> > >       make[1]: *** [../src/iLBC_define.h] Error 2
> > >       make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
> > >
> > > ### iLBC prepare stage failed

after this it continue compiling and dont stop at any stage. After this operation I shoot another command **ndk-build** it works fine but terminate compilation after showing below mentioned error

Compile thumb  : msilbc <= ilbc.c
jni/..//submodules/msilbc/ilbc.c:5:26: fatal error: iLBC_encode.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/msilbc/ilbc.o] Error 1

---

I got stuck at this stage, anybody can assist me to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance
Gulfam

Comment: Same problem, any idea what is the issue?